# WPF DataGrid individual row color

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, selecteditem

I have two datagrid. DG1 and DG2 with one column A (each) and many rows. Task is to highlight a particular row in one Datagrid when user selects row with same value in another datagrid. Example: User selects DG1 row 5, column A whose value is 'ABC'. 'ABC' is row 23, column A in DG2. Hence row 23 of DG should be highlighted in 'Red'.
This should work vice-versa (Clicking row 23 of DG2 should highlight row 5 of DG1).
Currently my code works by invoking the SelectedItem property of a Datagrid. And the down side to this is that there is an infinite loop of selection i.e. when user selects row 5 of DG1 it selects row 23 of DG2 which then kicks of selection for row 5 of DG1 which then kicks of selection of row 23 of DG2.
So a solution to my problem can be either to fix this infinite loop problem or provide a way to highlight a particular row of a datagrid with a specific color thus eliminating a call to selecteditem property of a datagrid altogether.

here is some code:

```
//This is the function invoked when a user selects a row in a DG1
    private void DG1SelectedItem(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (DG1.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            var val = DG1.SelectedItem; //Get the paticular row that was selected
            DataRowView row = (DataRowView)val;
            object[] list = row.Row.ItemArray;
            String rowValue = list[0].ToString(); //get the value within that selected row
            HighLightRow(DG2, account); //Call a function that highlights a particular row in a Datagrid with a given string value
        }

    }

    //This is the function invoked when a user selects a row in a DG2
    private void DG2SelectedItem(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (DG2.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            var val = DG2.SelectedItem; //Get the paticular row that was selected
            DataRowView row = (DataRowView)val;
            object[] list = row.Row.ItemArray;
            String rowValue = list[0].ToString(); //get the value within that selected row
            HighLightRow(DG1, account); //Call a function that highlights a particular row in a Datagrid with a given string value
        }

    }

    //Function to highlight the row in datagrid 'dg' with value of 'value' (only checks first column)
    private void HighLightRow(DataGrid dg, string value)
    {
        dg.UnselectAll();
        var itemsource = dg.ItemsSource as IEnumerable;
        int index = 0;
        ArrayList rowIndices = new ArrayList();
        //loop through entire datagrid looking for the string 'value' in the first column
        //if found, store the index in an array so it can be utillized to highlight all rows later on
        foreach (var item in itemsource)
        {
            DataRowView row = item as DataRowView;
            object[] list = row.Row.ItemArray;
            String valueToFind = list[0].ToString();
            if (valueToFind.Equals(value))
                rowIndices.Add(index);
            index++;
        }

        //For all rows where the string 'value' was foung in the first column of the datagrid, highlight it
        //Currently the implementation relies on SelectedItem
        for (int i = 0; i < rowIndices.Count; i++)
        {
            object item = dg.Items[(int)rowIndices[i]];
            dg.SelectedItem = item; //this code then invokes DG2SelectedItem (or DG1SelectedItem depending on which SelectedItem function was initially invoked) and we have the inifite loop problem
            **/*
            This is where I would like to select the row at the indices stored in rowIndices and highlight them red (and not rely on dg.SelectedItem like in the line above)
            Something like:
                dg.Row[i].Background = Brushes.Red;
            */**
            int m = dg.SelectedIndex;
            dg.UpdateLayout();
            dg.ScrollIntoView(dg.Items[m]);
        }
        dg.LoadingRow += Dg_LoadingRow;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Writing code in the code-behind of a Window or Control is not recommended in WPF. Using MVVM approach is far superior. You should consider moving to that paradigm.

Having said that, the solution to your problem is simple. Just introduce a global variable named `UpdateFlag`. Set it to `true` at the start of each grid's handler and to `false` at the end of the handler. At the very beginning of each handler (before setting the flag) check if this flag is `true` and exit the handler immediately if that is the case. This will stop the infinite recursion of selection change.

Some thing like this:

```
private bool UpdateFlag = false;
private void FirstHandler()
{
  if(UpdateFlag) return;

  UpdateFlag = true;

  //Do your highlighting here

  UpdateFlag = false;
}

private void SecondHandler()
{
  if(UpdateFlag) return;

  UpdateFlag = true;

  //Do your highlighting here

  UpdateFlag = false;
}
```